# Shoud I uninstall mongodb 2.6 before upgrade to 3.0?

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I installed mongodb 2.6 in my machine. This week, I followed the instructions in the subsection of **Install MongoDB** on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/. I installed MongoDB 3.0/. But I found that the date of some files in the mongodb package is in Feb. Why? Should I un-install mongodb 2.6 before upgrade to 3.0? my cluster is running all the time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not necessary to uninstall. 
I don't really like yum or apt for installing mongoDB. I suggest you to download the binaries from https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64 , linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.1.0.tgz (or the v12) and use it to start mongodb.

Comment: (1)I used apt to install mongodb in the past. apt installed lots of files in my computer, including binaries, scripts files. it also added some user and group in my computer. (2) when I used the apt to install mongodb3.0, it seems that the binaries of 2.6 were overwritten, but some files, such as mogno.conf was not. I have no idea.

Comment: mogno.conf should not be overwritten. Imagine to upgrade 100 servers with apt or yum and these tools replace your configuration.  Real nightmare...